# How to get all the plusones using the google+ api

Tags: google-api, google-plus

It seems the the google+ api is quite limited. I am simply trying to get the list of all the plusones of a user. does anyone know how to get that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to fetch a list of the URLs and posts that a user has +1ed. To see what information is returned by the Google+ API for a user, check the [Person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people). Only some of these fields are guaranteed, but the rest may be returned if they are publicly visible on the user's profile.

You can see who +1ed a particular Google+ post through an [Activity resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities), specifically, the `object.plusoners` field. The `activities.get` API call can fetch the Activity resource for a specified public post.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate.. is it planned in a future release? My work relies on what a person likes on Facebook, and I am trying to support google+ as an additional data source. Now, I am a little bit confused about what the google+ graph provides.

Comment: +1s and likes are not necessarily the best indicator of a person's interests. If you're trying to do something like recommendations, a text analysis of a person's posts could actually be much more powerful. Yes, that's not trivial, but there are plenty of sites that use this data to help power a recommendation engine. I think the same logic applies to other platforms too.